# Binary remainder not equal to the decimal remainder

Tags: divisibility, binary, binary-operations

I am having a weird result. I am dividing the binary number $10101010100000$ by $10011$.

In binary division. I get $R= 0100$ which is 4.

However, If I consider the decimal representation of the numbers then I will have that $10101010100000 = 10912$ and $10011 = 19$ And we all know that $10912$ divided $19$ gives a remainder of $6$ and not 4

I checked my results using all software you can imagine. And I still observe that the binary remainder is not equal to the decimal remainder. And I am going crazy !

Comment: The website you have linked is incorrect. If you don't believe me, try this: http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=110&den=101&f=d&e=1&m=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary remainder is wrong.

```
          1000111110    
      --------------  
10011)10101010100000  
      10011  
      -----  
         100101  
          10011  
         ------  
          100100  
           10011  
          ------  
           100010  
            10011  
            -----  
             11110  
             10011  
             -----  
              10110  
              10011  
              -----  
                 110
```

As you can see, the remainder is $110_{\text{two}}=6$.

Comment: I didn't make a mistake according to this http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=10101010100000&den=10011&f=d&e=1&m=1

Comment: @alkabary: That calculation is obviously wrong: its quotient is decimal $732$, and $732\cdot19=13908$, which is way too big.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align*}
10101010100000 -10011000000000&=10010100000\\
10010100000 - 1001100000 &= 1001000000\\
1001000000 - 100110000 &= 100010000\\
100010000 - 10011000 &= 1111000\\
1111000 - 1001100 &= 101100\\
101100 - 100110 &= 110
\end{align*}
$$
The remainder is 6.

Comment: I didn't make a mistake according to this http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=10101010100000&den=10011&f=d&e=1&m=1

Comment: Their first step is wrong. You can see for yourself that $10101010100000-10011000000000=10010100000$, not what they listed ($0110010100000$). Their math is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently you've made a mistake in binary division.

Comment: I didn't make a mistake according to this http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=10101010100000&den=10011&f=d&e=1&m=1

Comment: That site isn't doing binary arithmetic, it's doing polynomial computations over GF(2).